# Error installing Manjaro

Tags: manjaro

I'm Installing Manjaro KDE x64bits using Calamares.

The idea is to installed alongside Windows7 but when it is installing it crushes, showing next error:

```
Bad source
source="/bootmnt/manjaro/x86_64/root-image.sqfs"
```

My pc has not UEFI and in the past I have had installed Ubuntu with Windows 7 and after Manjaro Gnome with the windows 7, but this time it show an error.

When I'm in Calamares I select the option to install automatically with other system (windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had is that I made the bootable USB with Yumi. After remake the bootable USB with Rufus it worked well.

I find the answer in [this forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bad-source-error-in-installation/8737).

> That error is caused by bad iso, whether you incorrectly made the bootable drive or corrupted iso file. Always use dd to make your install media. What was your "one other problem" with dd?

So the best option to make a bootable USB of a Linux distro is, if you are in Linux, use dd command and if you have to do it in Windows, use Rufus.